# XSLT effective sequence based on values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to generate an effective sequence where the sequence number should reset after every change of value. Example:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/01/2015<date>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/05/2015<date>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/05/2015<date>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/10/2015<date>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/10/2015<date>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>B</name>
    <date>02/01/2015<date>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>B</name>
    <date>02/05/2015<date>
  </child>
</parent>
```

should give the following sequence result (i.e. everytime the combination of name and date changes, the sequence should reset to 0 and for each consecutive values that are same, it should increment the sequence number):

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/01/2015<date>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/05/2015<date>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/05/2015<date>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/10/2015<date>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>A</name>
    <date>02/10/2015<date>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>B</name>
    <date>02/01/2015<date>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
  </child>
  <child>
    <name>B</name>
    <date>02/05/2015<date>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor? Use a grouping approach adequate for your version and then number the items in each group.

Comment: I am using the XSLT 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a grouping problem, so you can use Muenchian grouping for this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kSequence" match="child" use="concat(name, '+', date)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
          select="child[generate-id() = 
                            generate-id(key('kSequence', concat(name, '+', date))[1])]"
          mode="group" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child" mode="group">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kSequence', concat(name, '+', date))" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      <sequence>
        <xsl:value-of select="position() - 1"/>
      </sequence>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, it produces the desired output. Note: this assumes that items with the same name and date occur together within your input XML. It looks like that should be a fair assumption in this case.

Comment: @DeepakGupta I urge to you reconsider changing your accepted answer. Even if it is easier to understand, using `preceding-sibling::` for grouping is horribly inefficient and a bad practice. My advice to you is to learn how to use Muenchian grouping. Once you understand it, the slight bit of complexity involved will not be a problem.

Comment: I totally get it and am already inclined towards using Muenchian grouping. Also, have been able to understand the logic using the link: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: My apologies - I did not realize I could choose only one solution and the other solution was marked later incorrectly making it the only solution. I have now chosen this as the solution which solved my problem and the one I am using. Thanks @JLRishe.

Comment: @DeepakGupta Much appreciated. It's only possible to accept one answer, but once you reach 100 rep points, you can upvote as many answers as you like.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternate approach, you might consider something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child">
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            <xsl:sort select="date"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="child">
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="date"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="name"/>
        <child>
            <sequence>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[date eq $date][name eq $name])"/>
            </sequence>
        </child>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This solution relies on presorting the xml elements and counting the number of matching preceding siblings.  You will find that this solution returns the same results as the grouping solution above and, while a bit more process intensive, might be considered a little easier to read.  You can improve the count of preceding siblings expression pretty easily, but I left things the way they were to be a bit more explicit.